# Fabric 2.x: tar and untar through pipe

Tags: python, ssh, tar, invoke, fabric

I want to do the equivalent of this shell script:

```
ssh visarend.solasistim.net tar -c /home/amoe/episodes | tar -vx -
```

But using Fabric 2.x.  This is my attempt, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
remote_path = "/home/amoe/episodes"

c = fabric.Connection('visarend.solasistim.net')

with subprocess.Popen(['tar', '-vx'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE) as reader_proc:
    c.run(
        "tar -c %s" % (remote_path,),
        out_stream=reader_proc.stdin
    )
```

This gives me the error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 525, in write_our_output
    stream.write(encode_output(string, self.encoding))

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Along with some [other errors](https://gist.github.com/amoe/26dd7508783da86046cb46eb52c9abeb).  I understand that it's probably because the stream that I get from `reader_proc.stdin` is a bytes stream, not a unicode stream.  But I don't understand why [run](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/runners.html#invoke.runners.Runner) would need a unicode stream, or what the correct change would be to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on why the task executed via `fabric.Connection.run()` is assumed to produce a text stream, however, thanks to the existence of the `latin-1` encoding, an actual binary stream packaged into a text stream object can be reinterpreted as a binary stream without any distortion:

```
import fabric
import subprocess
from io import TextIOWrapper

remote_path = "/home/amoe/episodes"

c = fabric.Connection('visarend.solasistim.net')

with subprocess.Popen(['tar', '-vx'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE) as reader_proc:
    c.run(
        "tar -c %s" % (remote_path,),
        out_stream=TextIOWrapper(reader_proc.stdin, encoding='latin-1'),
        encoding='latin-1'
    )
```

Comment: Very nice.. can you briefly elaborate on the significance of using `latin-1`?

Comment: @cody In fact any charmap encoding (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) will work. `latin-1` (aka `iso-8859-1`) is merely the simplest such encoding (it maps the continuous range of code points 0–255 to the bytes 0x0–0xff).